# What's the difference between iterative and frequentative aspects?

Tags: terminology, aspect

According to Wikipedia, the iterative aspect "[expresses the repetition of an event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_aspect)", and the frequentative aspect "[indicates repeated action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequentative)".

Is there a difference or are they synonyms?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bybee, Pagliuca and Perkins 1996 put it very nicely. Here's what they wrote.

Iterative "signals that an action is repeated on a single occasion and differs from the habitual and frequentative, which both signal the repetition occurred on different occasions" (p. 160). Here are the two examples they use:

*He searched for his keys all morning.* **iterative**

*He searched for his brother in every city he visited.* **frequentative**

Naturally, there is a lot of variation in linguistic terminology, esp. in aspect studies. Comrie 1976 argues for the importance of the iterative vs. habitual distinction; thus, the frequentative is viewed as a subclass of the habitual. Carslon 2012 does mention Van Geenhoven 2004, who views the frequentative as a subclass of the iterative; however, Carlson insists that Van Geenhoven 2004 terminology is not general usage.